# ImageIO.write() no crea archivo nuevo con formato JPG

Tags: java, imagen, bufferedimage

quiero escribir una nueva imagen con un formato diferente, estoy cargando una imagen **.png** y luego intento convertirle a **.jpg** con el siguiente metodo de la clase ImageIO:

```
public void guardarImagenDifFormatos(String ruta) {
        try {
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(ruta);
            ImageInputStream imageInputStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(input);
            BufferedImage imagenL = ImageIO.read(imageInputStream);

            ImageIO.write(imagenL, "jpg", new File(archivoImagen.getCurrentDirectory().toString()
                    +nombreOriginalImagen+".jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema con mi código anterior es que al concatenar la cadena de la dirección con la del nombre, hace falta el backslash entre las dos cadenas para podre crear una ruta válida para la creación de la imagen con el nuevo formato.

```
public void guardarImagenDifFormatos(String ruta) {
        try {
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(ruta);
            ImageInputStream imageInputStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(input);
            BufferedImage imagenL = ImageIO.read(imageInputStream);

            ImageIO.write(imagenL, "jpg", new File(archivoImagen.getCurrentDirectory().toString() +"\\"+
                    +nombreOriginalImagen+".jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
```

Bueno, si había una ruta válida, solo que tenía un nombre que incluía el nombre de la carpeta anterior + el nombre del archivo, es decir, estaba en el directorio anterior con ese nombre.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo de como puedes convertir tu imagen `png` en `jpg`:

**Código:**

```
public class ConvertImageFile {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedImage bufferedImage;

    try {

      //leemos la imagen png que queremos
      bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("c:\\javanullpointer.png"));

      // creamos un fondo blanco con la misma altura y anchura de la imagen.
      BufferedImage newBufferedImage = new BufferedImage(bufferedImage.getWidth(),
            bufferedImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
      newBufferedImage.createGraphics().drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, Color.WHITE, null);

      // indicamos la nueva imagen jpg
      ImageIO.write(newBufferedImage, "jpg", new File("c:\\javanullpointer.jpg"));

      System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

   }

}
```

Comment: Sigo sin entender porque no crea el archivo, ya hice la prueba con tu código, voy a la dirección donde estaba el anterior y ahí debería haberse creado el archivo con el mismo nombre pero con formato diferente, y no está.

Comment: Encontré el problema, al concatenar la cadena de la direccion con la del nombre olvidaba el backslash \ entre las dos cadenas. Gracias por tu respuesta.